Finding type of List on Scala case class declared field via reflection
I have a Scala case class with a List declared as:
  AuxiliaryImages: List[MimeInfo],

I get the field type using reflection:
  private def ft(fieldName: String): Class[_] = {
    val field = classOf[CatalogItemRecord].getDeclaredField(fieldName)
    field.getType
  }

I need conditional logic based on the type of the List:
  if (ft("AuxiliaryImages") == classOf[List[MimeInfo]]) {

But it seems I'm losing the list type List[MimeInfo]] as I get scala.collection.immutable.List for the field type.
Is there a way to get the list type List[MimeInfo]] via reflection on declared fields?

That is because of type erasure at runtime. Depends on which version of scala you are using, the approach to solve your issue is different. You can find more information at Preserving Type Information at Runtime in Scala 2. I haven't explored scala 3 so much to know how to do it properly

I'm wondering why you need to use reflection. Scala has a powerful type system to avoid using reflection. I'm wondering if you already considered other techniques such as ADT, Type classes, higher order functions, etc

What is the meta-problem you are trying to solve?

@GastónSchabas Type erasure is irrelevant. If you have an instance of type Foo[Bar] then indeed Java runtime sees it as Foo[_]. But if you have a class with a field of type Foo[Bar] then Java runtime knows that it's specifically Foo[Bar].

You should use Field#getGenericType instead of Field#getType. Try
def ft(fieldName: String): (Class[_], Seq[Class[_]]) = {
  val field = classOf[CatalogItemRecord].getDeclaredField(fieldName)
  field.getGenericType match {
    case pt: ParameterizedType =>
      val cls = pt.getRawType match {
        case c: Class[_] => c
      }
      val argClasses = pt.getActualTypeArguments.map {
        case c: Class[_] => c
      }.toSeq
      (cls, argClasses)
  }
}

ft("AuxiliaryImages") == (classOf[List[_]], Seq(classOf[MimeInfo])) // true i.e. List[MimeInfo]
ft("AuxiliaryImages") == (classOf[List[_]], Seq(classOf[Int])) // false i.e. not List[Int]

